# How do you scrape a website that doesn't have specific html tags with represented with class names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am scraping a used car [website](https://jammer.ie/used-cars) I've got the make, model, year, and miles but I don't know how to get the others due to them being the li tag as well. I've put all my code here

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://jammer.ie/used-cars'
response = requests.get(url)
response.status_code
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup
results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'span-9 right-col'})
len(results)
results[0].find('h6',{'class':'car-make'}).get_text()
results[0].find('p', {'class':'model'}).get_text()
results[0].find('p', {'class': 'year'}).get_text()
results[0].find('li').get_text().replace('\n', "")
```

I get the information I want from the above code but for other parts of the li tags they have img tags and span tags how can I get the information from each of the li tags?
I am new to python so would like it to be somewhat simply and explained to me please

I tired using the img tag but don't think I used it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all features into a dataframe you can do:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://jammer.ie/used-cars"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for car in soup.select(".car"):
    info = car.select_one(".top-info").get_text(strip=True, separator="|")
    make, model, year, price = info.split("|")

    features = {}
    for feature in car.select(".car--features li"):
        k = feature.img["src"].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        v = feature.span.text
        features[f"feature_{k}"] = v

    all_data.append(
        {"make": make, "model": model, "year": year, "price": price, **features}
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| make | model | year | price | feature_speed | feature_engine | feature_transmission | feature_owner | feature_door-icon1 | feature_petrol5 | feature_paint | feature_hatchback |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ford | Fiesta | 2010 | €5,950 | 113144 miles | 1.4 litres | Manual | 4 previous owners | 5 doors | Diesel | Silver | Hatchback |
| Volkswagen | Polo | 2013 | Price on application | 41000 miles | 1.2 litres | Automatic | nan | 5 doors | Petrol | Blue | Hatchback |
| Volkswagen | Polo | 2015 | Price on application | 27000 miles | 1.2 litres | Automatic | nan | 5 doors | Petrol | Red | Hatchback |
| Audi | A1 | 2014 | Price on application | 45000 miles | 1.4 litres | Automatic | nan | 3 doors | Petrol | White | Hatchback |
| Audi | A3 | 2014 | Price on application | 79000 miles | 1.4 litres | Automatic | nan | 5 doors | Petrol | White | Hatchback |
| Audi | A3 | 2008 | €4,450 | 147890 miles | 1.6 litres | Automatic | 3 previous owners | 3 doors | Petrol | Black | Hatchback |
| SEAT | Alhambra | 2018 | €29,950 | 134000 miles | 2.0 litres | Manual | 2 previous owners | 5 doors | Diesel | White | MPV |
| Volkswagen | Jetta | 2014 | €8,950 | 138569 miles | 1.6 litres | Manual | 3 previous owners | 4 doors | Diesel | Grey | Saloon |
| Volkswagen | Beetle | 2014 | Price on application | 66379 miles | 1.2 litres | Automatic | 1 previous owners | 2 doors | Petrol | Black | Hatchback |
| Volvo | XC60 | 2019 | €44,950 | 38214 miles | 2.0 litres | Automatic | 1 previous owners | 5 doors | Diesel | Black | Estate |
| Toyota | Aqua | 2014 | Price on application | 67405 miles | 1.5 litres | Automatic | 1 previous owners | 5 doors | nan | White | Hatchback |
| Audi | A3 | 2014 | Price on application | 51182 miles | 1.4 litres | Automatic | 1 previous owners | 4 doors | Petrol | Black | Saloon |
| Volkswagen | Golf | 2014 | Price on application | 68066 miles | 1.2 litres | Automatic | 1 previous owners | 5 doors | Petrol | Blue | Hatchback |